# Given $G$, when can we find a division ring $R$ with $R^*=G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

This is motivated by [a characterization of finite cyclic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346936/finite-group-for-which-xxm-e-leq-m-for-all-m-is-cyclic), in which one proves

> Let $G$ be a finite group. If $\#\{g\in G\colon g^d=e\}$ is at most $d$, then $G$ is cyclic.

The proof is not actually difficult, but a unnecessarily complicated idea occurred to me (maybe because the first time I saw such a result, it was used to prove that finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic).

If we can construct this $G$ as the multiplicative group of a certain division ring, that is, $R^*\colon=\{r\in R\colon r\neq 1\}$. Then we know $G$ is abelian since [finite division rings are commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem), and the abelian case follows from a direct use of [the structure theorem of finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).

Of course such a proof is unnecessarily complicated and very likely results in some *cyclic* arguments since it uses two *very big* structure theorems. But I guess it would still be nice to know what kind of groups are multiplicative groups of division rings.

Thanks very much!

Comment: This is certainly not always possible. Recently a question was posed here to prove that there are no rings at all (let alone division rings) whose group of invertibles has order $5$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I have the feeling that this is in general not possible. But I wonder whether there is some nice way to know when this is possible.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring.

Comment: Pretty sure this question has been asked before. There is a positive answer possible under several restrictions described at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156363/result-due-to-cohn-unique-division-ring-whose-unit-group-is-a-given-group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The answer" for classifying which *finite* groups are subgroups of units of division rings was given by Amitsur in *Finite subgroups of division rings.* Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1955), 361–386. This is generally considered to be the analogue of the "finite subgroups cyclic" theorem for the unit groups of fields.

(In [Lam's paper on the quaternions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.berkeley.edu%2F~lam%2Fhtml%2Fquat.ps&ei=3aSTUcHMLKzQywHFwoDIDA&usg=AFQjCNEhGBJ0fS7Ri9EoPFVP8prGrwxjgQ&sig2=gsiwyj8fkATvFnslmgmLyQ&bvm=bv.46471029,d.aWc), he describes an interesting lead-up to that discovery about Coexeter's work determining the finite subgroups of $\Bbb H^\ast$.)

This clearly acts as "local" restrictions on elements of finite order.